# External Hard Drive: Is it bad or still good to use?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have an external HDD (Seagate Backup Plus 2TB) and it had some problems lately, therefore I had run some test on it and it turned out to have some… problems, if I can call them like that. Below are some screenshots.

---

- HD Sentinel:

[image: HD Sentinel]

---

- After running `chkdsk /f /r /x`:

[image: chkdsk]

---

I would send it to warranty but the shipping to Seagate would cost me as much as I've paid for it. **My question: is it safe to use it, or should I throwing it away and buy another one?**

Comment: You should use the [manufacturers tools](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/seatools/) for testing when they are available

Comment: If you don't need to be able to read the data back off it then it's ok to carry on using it. I guess you'd just like someone else to confirm your suspicion that yes, you should buy another external HDD. Have a read of some of the items linked to in the "Related" section on this page.